# Check if each ip of a file is present or not in another file, then acting in consequence

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have iplist.txt containing a list of ip I want to ban (one by line, extracted from a file.log and corresponding a certain condition like 3 or more access);
I want to check for each ip of iplist.txt if it is already or not in iptables via its presence or not in file.dump (the iptables I've exported from iptables-save > file.dump):

```
iplist.txt
123.123.123.123
234.234.234.234
222.111.222.111
...


file.dump
-A INPUT -s 123.123.123.123/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 111.222.111.222/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 234.234.234.234/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 126.127.126.127/32 -j DROP
...
```

bash script which checks in a 30 seconds loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 = 1 ]
do

# checking the presence or not of each ip I want to ban from iplist.txt, in file.dump
ip2ban=$(cat iplist.txt)
for i in $ip2ban
do
ipcheck=$(egrep -o "$ip2ban" file.dump)
if [ -z "$ipcheck" ]
# if $ip2ban is not present in file.dump
then
echo "$ip2ban is NOT in file.dump file then I BAN IT!"
# command to ban via iptables here
sleep 1
else
# if $ip2ban is already present in file.dump
echo "$ip2ban is in file.dump then I do nothing and continue!"
sleep 1
fi
sleep 30
done

done
exit
```

It is not working as it seems to check the whole iplist.txt contain at a time, not each line after the previous one!?

```
I got this:
123.123.123.123
234.234.234.234
222.111.222.111 is in file.dump then I do nothing and continue!

but I should got that:
123.123.123.123 is in file.dump then I do nothing and continue!
234.234.234.234 is in file.dump then I do nothing and continue!
222.111.222.111 is NOT in file.dump file then I BAN IT!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
ipcheck=$(egrep -o "$ip2ban" file.dump)
```

you have `egrep -o "$ip2ban"`. And `ip2ban` contains your whole file: `ip2ban=$(cat iplist.txt)`

You need to change the line `ipcheck=$(egrep -o "$ip2ban" file.dump)` to:

```
ipcheck=$(egrep -o "$i" file.dump)
```

Comment: Oh obviously, I've defined the 'i' variable but I've forgot to use it ^^ ; thank you Mikolaj ; I've also moved last 'sleep 30' after 1rst 'done' ; that works!